# Переопределенный метод стринг работает только если вызываю его явно

Tags: java, testng

Изначальный код выглядел так:

[image]

Списки выглядят так:

[image]

А сообщение было такое:

[image]

Затем при поэлементной проверке оказалось, что если не вызывать метод `toString` явно, то сравнение возвращает `false`, а если вызывать явно, то `true`

Переопределенный метод `toString`:

[image]

В итоге код, который заработал:

[image]

**В чем была проблема?**

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba?cb=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При сравнении одного объекта класса `Student` из списка `students1` с другим объектом класса `Student` из списка `students2` у одного из них вызывается метод `equals(Object other)`. Это метод класса `Object`, и по умолчанию он сравнивает, указывают ли ссылки на один и тот же объект в памяти, если нет - возвращает `false`. Т.е. он ***не** сравнивает результат вызова метода toString()*.

Хотя в сравниваемых объектах класса Student все поля идентичны, без переопределения метода `equals()` программа не знает, как конкретно их сравнивать, поэтому сравнивает ссылки.
Предположу, что в списки `students1` и `students2` были помещены не одни и те же объекты, а разные объекты, созданные через вызов оператора `new` и помещение в конструкторы идентичных данных, и хотя строчное представление объектов идентично, сами объекты в памяти - разные.

Поэтому в классе `Student` необходимо переопределить метод `equals`, например вот так:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;
    Student student = (Student) other;
    return Objects.equals(id, student.id) && Objects.equals(name, student.name);;
}
```

Также в большинстве случаев рекомендовано вместе с методом `equals()` переопределять метод `hashCode()`. Об этом довольно много написано, также информацию об этом можно найти в [исходном коде на сайте Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Спасибо
А почему тогда в результате теста `Expected` и `Actual` одинаковые, разве тогда и там и там не должны быть ссылки, если сравнивались они? Я поэтому и подумала, что метод `toString` вызывается не явно

Comment: @riric сам фреймворк для тестов для наглядности выводит в консоль результаты через `toString()`, чтобы пользователю проще было понять что сравнивалось. если бы у вас `toString()` не был переопределен, то вы бы увидели что-то типа *"expected: Student@1828, actual: Student@1996"*. кстати в дебаге на второй картинке именно в таком виде указано название объектов до их строчных представлений (это дефолтный результат вывода `toString()`), что и говорит о том, что ссылки на объекты разные